# Thread safety isseus while reading from or writing to a session

Tags: session, servlets, thread-safety, session-variables

The author says here:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/session-and-clustered-java-web
that:

> With servlets, you have the power to put objects into and take objects out of session yourself. Alone, this presents thread-safety issues....

Now session is one per user. So as part of a user request, when the user is manipulating the session, no otehr request can manipulate the same session. So how we will have thread safety issues here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same user using the same browser and opening more than one tab, then it is possible two requests manipulating the same session.